# Most sets without an exact cover

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Given a population $P$, and sets of size $N$, how many sets can you have without having an exact cover over $P$?

By exact cover, I mean a set of sets that contains all elements in $P$ exactly once.

For example, if $P = 4$ and $N = 2$, you can have at most $3$ sets:  $\{A, B\}, \{A, C\}, \{A, D\}$.   Any other set would allow an exact covering (the set $\{B, C\}$ could pair with $\{A, D\}$ for an exact covering)

It's important to note here that $P$ needs to be a multiple of $N$ for this to be interesting at all.

I'm curious if there's a simple formula for the above.  I feel like this should be a well-covered sequence, but I couldn't find it on OEIS.

Comment: Can you add a definition of "perfect cover"?

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter does that suffice?

Comment: @NathanMerrill so are you saying $A$ is a perfect cover of $P$ if for every $x \in P, \exists! X \in A$ such that $x \in X$?

Comment: Oh!  I realized I used the wrong term.  The term is [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) (at least according to wikipedia).

Answer (score 1):

Fix any $a_0 \in P$. How many subsets of size $N$ of $P$ do not contain $a_0$?

Well, if $Q=P-\{a_0\}$ (so we took $a_0$ out), $Q$ has $|P|-1$ elements, and we can choose any $N$ of them to make a subset of size $N$, so there are $(|P|-1) \choose N$ subsets which don't include $a_0$. Let $X$ then be the set of all subsets of size $N$ which don't include $a_0$, and we prove that this maximally doesn't contain an exact covering of $P$. I.e $X \cup I$ contains a subset which is an exact cover for $P$ where $I \notin X$ is any subset of $P$ of size $N$.

First, $I \notin X$ so necessarily $a_0 \in I$. Without loss of generality (or simply by relabelling the elements of $P$) let $I=\{a_0, \cdots, a_{n-1} \}, \mbox{where} \ a_i \in P, 0\leq i \leq |P|-1$.

But by definition of $X$, $\{a_n, \cdots, a_{2n-1} \}, \cdots, \{a_{|P|-n-1}, \cdots a_{|P|-1} \} \in X$, as none if these sets contain $a_0$. But these exact sets, along with $I$ form an exact cover for $P$, so we cannot add $I$ to $X$ without forming exact covers.

So $X$ has maximum number of elements, with size $(|P|-1) \choose N$

Comment: I think all there is left to prove is to show that all sets which maximally don't contain a subset which forms an exact cover of $P$ has size equal or less than the size of $X$

Comment: I agree.  This is a really good lower bound, but I my maximal example in the question doesn't actually follow this format.  Still, $(P-1) \choose N$ is far higher than I thought it would be.

Comment: @NathanMerrill can you give examples of when this doesn't work? I genuinely thought that this would be the correct number I just havent managed to quite prove it fully but maybe examples might give insight as to why this is merely a lower bound

Comment: @NathanMerrill or did you mean the example in the question (which is what you wrote oops). In your example it does work - P has size 4, N is 2, ${(P-1) \choose N} = {3\choose2} =3$ is the number if sets you had in your example

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  You are totally right:  My example in the question doesn't follow the format you describe but it isn't higher than the construction you give.  Therefore, I believe that its possible there *could* be an example with more elements (but I have no idea what that would be).

Comment: @NathanMerrill ahh my bad, but yes I do agree with you! It does seem plausible my construction does give the highest value but I can't seem to prove it - or rather havent invested much time to prove it